# Prove that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2\sin\left(\frac{i\pi}{n}\right) \to\frac{1}{\pi} - \frac{4}{\pi^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $$u_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2\,\sin\left(\frac{i\,\pi}{n}\right)$$

Prove that $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{i}{n}\right)^2\,\sin\left(\dfrac{i\,\pi}{n}\right) = 
\dfrac{1}{\pi} - \dfrac{4}{\pi^3}$$

I know that I can express $\sin\left(\dfrac{i \pi}{n}\right)$ with complex, using Euler's relation $\sin \theta = \dfrac{1}{2i}(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})$, but I don't know how to use (or even if I can use it).

Comment: "Prove" is a verb, as in "Prove that...". "Proof" is a noun, as in "Provide me with a proof that..."

Comment: Your notation is a bit confusing. $i$ as iterator under the sum sign and as $\sqrt{-1}$ confused (at least) me.

Comment: @dotdot It is common to use $i$ when indexing a sum. You will also see $j,k$, for example.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: I normally use $m$,$n$ or $q$ :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Riemann sum:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{i}{n}\right)^2\,\sin\left(\dfrac{i\,\pi}{n}\right) = \int_0^1 dx \: x^2 \sin{\pi x}$$

Comment: You missed $\pi$!

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: thanks.

Comment: You also beat me to it. Why did I waste time with grammar? =)

Comment: ....and you integrate by parts.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Well, let's leave something for the OP to work out.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff and let's leave +1 to RonGordon.